# I am trying to print JSON in go

Tags: json, api, go, spotify

How can I print JSON? when I print I keep on getting random numbers in an array is there a way to print JSON instead of parsing it?
Here's the function in the main.go

```
 func sendpostget(word string) {

// Create a new spotify object
spot := spotify.New("number", "number")

// Authorize against Spotify first
authorized, _ := spot.Authorize()
if authorized {

    // If we ere able to authorize then Get a simple album
    //  s := join("artists/", phone)
    s := "artists/xxxx/albums?market=ES&limit=2"
    fmt.Println(s)
    response, _ := spot.Get(s, nil)
    fmt.Println(response)

}

// Parse response to a JSON Object and

 }
```

Here is the struct that I am using ( this get method will retrieve an artists' album from spotify API )

```
type Albums struct {
    Albums []Album `json:"users"`
}

    type Album struct {
    AlbumType string `json:"album_type"`
    Href      string `json:"href"`
    ID        string `json:"id"`
}
```

Comment: Start by printing the error of `authorized, _ := spot.Authorize()` instead of throwing it away, it might tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You are giving too much information in your URL. It is really supposed to be an endpoint. If you read the package's code, you'll see that they take the endpoint you give and prepend it with the `BASE_URL` and `API_VERSION`. Also, take the previous advice and stop ignoring errors. They are there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I actually found out I'm giving the http spotify api link to the string when I shouldn't. It now worked but the problem is it is returning a JSON file and it's my first time parsing JSON and it is not working do you know how can I print JSON as a first step before parsing it? I will update my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting a load of numbers as a JSON body instead of text then probably it's an array of byte instead of a string.  To fix this, convert to string

```
response, _ := spot.Get(s, nil)
    fmt.Println(string(response))
```